# amazon ec2, postfix, SES set up?

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, postfix-mta

I'm trying to set up an SES(simple email service) with aws.
(followed instruction on http://pandali.com/cgi-bin/pforum/pforum.pl?num=1297885604/2)

**In nutshell,

It seems I've successfully sent a request email to amazon.(no error msgs)

Amazon is supposed to send an email to abc@example.com.

I check /var/mail, but nothing is there.**

I suspect it's because my domain name (example.com) is not set up correctly? 
or postfix is not set up correctly

my postfix's `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu) biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


myhostname = a.example.com 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases 
myorigin = example.com
mydestination = example.com, ip-10-212-82-**.ec2.internal, localhost.ec2.internal, localhost 
relayhost = mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = + 
inet_interfaces = all 
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Both of a.example.com and example.com is mapped to this ec2 instance.
(I can ssh to example.com)

'hostname' shows ip-10-212-**-**.

Comment: Do you have MX records set for your domains? Whether you can SSH to the domain only means there's an A or CNAME record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open SMTP(25)/SMTPS(465) ports to send emails and POP3(110)/POP3S(995) or IMAP(143)/IMAPS(993) ports to receive emails on your ec2 instance.